# Sufficient conditions to approximate the expectation of a ratio of two values with the ratio of the expected values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, expected-value

Given a random variable $X:\Omega\to E$, let $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:E\to\mathbb{R}$.

When $\mathbb{E}_X\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]$ can be approximated by $\frac{\mathbb{E}_X[f(x)]}{\mathbb{E}_X[g(x)]}$? More formally, what are sufficient conditions, which depend also on $\alpha>0$, ensuring that (*at least one of*) the following inequalities hold?

$$\mathbb{E}_X\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]\le\alpha\frac{\mathbb{E}_X[f(x)]}{\mathbb{E}_X[g(x)]}~,$$

$$\mathbb{E}_X\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]\ge\alpha\frac{\mathbb{E}_X[f(x)]}{\mathbb{E}_X[g(x)]}~.$$

Comment: Even though I know only a limited number of results of this kind, I still have to say that your setup is too broad to have something interesting. Maybe you would kindly tell the set up of your underlying problem?

Comment: The underlying problem concerns the choice of a hyperplane selected uniformly at random in a Euclidean space, partitioning a cloud of points into two subsets. We have two functions $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ based on the two subsets. Calculating that ratio of these two functions' expected value is easy, but I need to calculate the expected ratio of these two functions, which seems much harder. Hence, I would content myself with an approximation of the expected ratio, and I was curious to know under what assumptions we can derive such approximation from the two expectations ratio.

Comment: Can we state anything based on some kind of distance between $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Hm, so you have a high dimensional object. I tried to think about it but it is not easy.

Comment: Your question is related to high dimensional concentration measure, you might wanna ask someone who has expertise on this subject.

Comment: It would be great for me to have a result even when the number of dimensions is $2$ (so the "hyperplane" is clearly a straight line). By the way, why do you think that the "concentration measure" is necessarily involved here? I was thinking about some conditions on $f$, $g$ and the probabilities of each outcomes, without involving concentration measure results, but maybe I am wrong. What is the "limited number of results of this kind" you mentioned at the beginning of your first message?

Comment: Conditions on $f,g$ are surely necessary, I have something already in my mind. I mention that subject, especially in the high-dimensional direction,  because it's focused on studying the geometric relation, randomness  and inequality

Comment: Limited results are FKG's inequality, for example, Hoeffding is also okay, some concentrations about Gaussian measures are also okay.

Comment: Stein's method can also be used if needed, they are all from Concentration Measure field. But it's a vast major which I do not recommend to have a quick read ( it's hard to come up with anything if you just have a vague idea about a broad object)

Comment: But none of them seems to be able to apply directly to your set up. Some careful treatment of your framework should be done, and I didn't have much experience in it.